# How to filter list of custom post type with 2 custom taxonomy with ajax in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i've a custom post type that i called it `app` with 2 custom taxonomy that i called them `app_platform` and `app_category`

and now in `taxonomy-app_platform.php` page i wanna show whole of apps with specifed app platform along with a drop-down list that shows list of `app_category` like this .

[image]

so in the end . i able to filer list app with specifed `app_platform` and `app_category`

**Note That:** in the first time that page is loaded i just wanna show whole of apps in specifed app platform . for exmaple whole of android application

how can i do it with ajax and good performance?

Comment: Well if rendering select * hurts your page load time then you have to use pagination by using relative record numbers and range with your query

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a wordpress issue (I believe) you are likely using MySQL to store your data which means you can't use CTEs. What you will have to do is something like this:

In `$(document).ready` return your result set in JSON write a query something like this:

```
"SELECT DISTINCT FROM table where AppCategory = 'iPhone 7` LIMIT 0, 50"
```

This would return 50 records of that category.

Inside the AJAX call you would then populate the select list based on these results.

I will need more info to take you any further.

Comment: thanks yardpenalty but i to be honest . i didn't understand what you've mentioned . coluld you please clarify your answer

Comment: Can you offer more info on how you are populating your data? I need to know is this a client-side request and how your are setting the parameters of the query. Thanks in advance

Comment: i just use standard wordpres  loop to get post type in `taxonomy-app_platform.php` page.